# How to subtract time in Date.js or Day.js? (more than 24h)

Tags: javascript, momentjs, dayjs

I want to subtract for example "**01:30:00**" from "**37:30:00**".

What is the best way to do it, *considering that I have not found the possibility if it is longer than 24 hours.*

Is there any workaround for this in js?

I want to see "**36:00:00**" as result.

```
const time1 = dayjs("01:00:00", 'HH:mm:ss').add(37,'hours')
const time2 = dayjs("01:00:00", 'HH:mm:ss')

const diffInMilliseconds = time1.diff(time2)
const diffInHours = dayjs.duration(diffInMilliseconds).hours()
console.log(diffInHours) // log: 13
```

Comment: The difference is 36 hours, not 37. Adding 37 will make the time be `38:30:00`